# pentaho CDE with protovis

Tags: html, render, pentaho, dashboard, pentaho-cde

i m new to data Pentaho CDE .
I am trying to get Protovis working Pentaho CDE . Here is sample code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="protovis.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript+protovis">
    var panel = new pv.Panel()
.width(160).height(160)
.bottom(10).left(10).right(30);
panel.add(pv.Area)
.data([1, 1.2, 1.7, 1.5, .7, .5, .2])
.bottom(0)
.height(function(d) d * 80)
.left(function() this.index * 25)
.fillStyle("lightblue")
.anchor("top").add(pv.Line)
.strokeStyle("black")
.add(pv.Dot);
panel.add(pv.Rule)
.bottom(0)
.add(pv.Rule)
.data(pv.range(.5, 2, .5))
.bottom(function(d) d * 80)
.strokeStyle("white")
.anchor("right").add(pv.Label);
panel.render()
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

now how to get pento CDE integrate with protovis?

any Help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Protovis Component in CDE.
One of the properties for that component is the custom protovis script.

So, to integrate your script into CDE, I'd move it to a standalone js file in the solution repository.
Then I'd create a Protovis Component in my CDE dashboard and point it at that js file.

That should do it!

Comment: thanks for the comment @Pedro, but i add simple js file to component, then it wont run, may be any file needed. If you could provide any link , that would be helpful.

Comment: Check logs, both server side and on the browser. That should give you a hint